# What do the latest FERMI results say about dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter, telescopes, gamma-rays

There was an announcement at a recent UCLA symposium on dark matter by the [FERMI collaboration](http://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/) which hints at some evidence of dark matter.  The results aren't yet published, but the [symposium news release is here](http://m.ucla.edu/newsroom/item.php?name=News&path=http%3A%2F%2Fnewsroom.ucla.edu%2Fportal%2Fucla%2Ffiles%2Fmobile.xml&article=Possible+evidence+for+dark+matter+particle+presented&signature=18ef784085eaa0c6a3c40872eac84dbe&no_server_init).  Most of the news release is just general dark matter fluff, but it says that

> One search technique involves using the vast amount of dark matter in our galaxy. The NASA Fermi Satellite Telescope, an international collaboration involving NASA, the Goddard Space Flight Center and the SLAC National Accelerator Laboratory, searches for gamma rays — very high-energy light particles — from this dark matter.
>
> There are models of dark matter that would allow a signal in the galactic dark matter consistent with the claims at the meeting and provide a small interaction consistent with the "null results" in the direct dark matter searches all over the world.

This obviously doesn't contain much information.  Can anyone closer to the field expound on the findings?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it's probably related to [this arXiv preprint](http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/1402.6703.pdf) (pdf). Figure 7 (on page 8) shows a strong likeness between the WIMP annihilation spectrum and the *Fermi* observed spectrum.

Comment: Note also that the authors of the linked paper are, as far as I know, not part of the Fermi Collaboration (or at least they're not on the few Fermi Collaboration papers I've read).

Comment: I talked with my resident *Fermi* expert and he rolled his eyes when I mentioned the above paper. Turns out that author is regularly claiming DM in the galactic center. If his detections were true, my expert says, then we'd be seeing DM profiles in dwarf galaxies and clusters, but we're not.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for looking into this.  Do you want to turn it into an answer?  If you do, I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two recent papers, [one relating to the galactic center](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6703v1.pdf) and [the other relating to dwarf galaxies](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.89.042001).

The galactic center article concludes that excess gamma rays in the 1-3 GeV range consistent with the annihilation of dark matter particles in the 31-40GeV range are observed. Conclusions about the density profile of dark matter in the galactic center are also made.

With respect to dwarf galaxies the Fermi teams says they have observed "a small but provocative gamma-ray excess", but that there is a 1 in 12 chance that the excess isn't actually signal. (quoting from [this press release](http://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/fermi-data-tantalize-with-new-clues-to-dark-matter/)).